# kotlin: Mutable property type in a data class

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, data-class

I have the following data class that implements `Parcelable`:

```
data class Car(
    val createdAt: String? = "",
    val updatedAt: String? = "",
    val id: String? = "",
    val name: String? = "",
    val user: User? = User()
)
```

In this data class, sometimes the `user` attributes can be **the id of the user** (String) and sometimes it could be **the User object itself**.

Is there any way to implement Parcelable and indicates that the value can be either a String or an Object ? (Another data model)

Comment: User should be parcelable as well. When you unparcel Car you might have both or just one of the two information.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is the right answer to your question, but I think that a sealed class may help you.
Basically you could define a `MutableUser` (User or string) and each subclass of MutableUser should implement `Parcelable`.

```kotlin
sealed class MutableUser : Parcelable {
    @Parcelize
    class UserAttribute(val user: User) : MutableUser()

    @Parcelize
    class SimpleAttribute(val userId: String) : MutableUser()
}
```

Then, you could use this `MutableUser` in your car data model like below:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class Car(
   val createdAt: String? = "",
   val updatedAt: String? = "",
   val id: String? = "",
   val name: String? = "",
   val user: MutableUser
) : Parcelable
```